# "He finishes eating" vs. "He finishes BY eating" (By + Gerund)

Tags: gramática, gerundio

¿Como se puede diferenciar entre estos dos sentidos?

Que yo sepa la forma de escribirlo en castellano en los dos casos es «termina comiendo.»

Pero en ingles son frases con significados muy diferentes: «He finishes eating the dessert» vs. «He finishes BY eating the dessert»

Para ser más claro, ejemplos más extendidos:

> He finishes eating the meal.
>
> He finishes (eating the meal) by eating the dessert.

Ojalá que esté claro que hay dos acciones, una accion más grande que está terminando haciendo la segunda acción.

> He finishes fixing the computer.
>
> He finishes (fixing the computer) by putting in the last screw.

¿Cómo se puede diferenciar en castellano el significado?

Comment: puedes dar un ejemplo de su uso en inglés?

Comment: Ok, voy a editarla.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para expresar la finalización de una acción única, yo diría:

- Acaba/termina de comer (*He finishes eating*).

Por ejemplo :

- Llámame cuando acabes de comer (*Call me when you finish eating*)

El gerundio indica la simultaneidad de dos eventos o acciones. Por tanto, la expresión "termina/acaba comiendo" debe estar relacionada con otra acción. Este es el caso de la construcción inglesa "he finishes by eating... ":

- Terminamos la reunión comiendo unos dulces que había traído un colega (*We finished the meeting by eating some sweets that a colleague had brought*).

*Terminar/acabar+gerundio* también se puede utilizar para predecir el resultado de una costumbre actual (en inglés, *end up + -ing*):

- Si sigues comiendo tanta grasa, acabarás teniendo problemas de salud (*If you keep eating so much fat, you will end up having health problems*).

Answer (score 0):

"by" introduces another mean that is being used to aid the first verb "finishes." They don't even have to be related. He could be engaged in an activity such as "cooking" which he then finishes "by" eating what he cooked.
"finishes eating" here finishes is not being seen as a somewhat separate action but rather one that is describing what stage of "eating" he is at.